# Как правильно обратиться к response внутри другого callback | NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

Есть код на express:

```
app.put('/', (req, res) => {
   pool.query(checkValueString, (err, res1) => {
            console.log(err, res1)
            if(res1.rows.length != 0){
                res.send('There is an entry in the database with this priority value')
            }
        })
})
```

как обратиться к res внутри if, если это не получается так как во второй функции можно работать только с err, res1.

Comment: а Вы пробовали обратиться к `res`? Что говорит консоль?

Comment: res.send in not a function

Comment: так может этот аргумент вообще не передается  в коллбэк?

Comment: передаётся res1, а мне надо из коллбэка обратиться к res.

Comment: у меня складывается впечатление, что Вам необходимо почитать про области видимости. На строчке, перед `pool.query....` напишите `console.log(res)` или `console.log(...arguments)` - и Вы увидите - передается ли `res`